# Advanced Jquery | Scroll Nav Selected

Tags: jquery

I need help with selecting a li element when a user scrolls to a particular section on a page:

See here for my progress: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/349/

If you click on the "services" link the text color should change to red as you are on that section of the page, same again if you were to click on "home" or "contact".

I have an idea regarding the jquery is that you'd need to be able to add and remove classes to the LI so that the css can pick up the selected class and render as per.

The functionality can be viewed here: http://demicreative.com/#capabilities

If you scroll down and see the work section you will notice the nav item is selected - I am after the same functionality.

Comment: What just happened? You accepted my answer then unaccepted it. Is something missing?

Comment: Stackoverflow was playing up - it's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var header_height = $('#nav').outerHeight();
var sections = [];
$('#nav a').each(function(){    
    var section = $(this.hash).offset()
    sections.push({
        'link':$(this).parent(),
        'top' : $(this.hash).offset().top-header_height,
        'bottom' : $(this.hash).offset().top + $(this.hash).outerHeight() -header_height
    });
});

$('#nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - header_height
    }, 500);
});


$(window).scroll(function(){   
    for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++)
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= sections[i].top &&
           $(window).scrollTop() <= sections[i].bottom){
            sections[i].link.addClass('selected')
                .siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
});​
```

I attached the event directly to links in the `#nav`. I add the selected class to the parent element and remove the it from the parent element's siblings. I also make the scroll offset 70 px less, the height of the nav and it's padding.

**Updated:** There is no reference to any particular section only sections this means if you expand, adding new links or sections it will still work without having to updated the JavaScript.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/5Ta8j/

Comment: This is the correct code - thank you very much p.s I did not down vote - I voted up

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - $('#nav').outerHeight()}, 500);
   $('.scroll').removeClass('selected')  
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/354/

---

try this:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - $('#nav').outerHeight()}, 500);
   $('.scroll').removeClass('selected')  
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
   var hdr = $('#header').offset().top - $('#nav').outerHeight();  
   var svc = $('#services').offset().top - $('#nav').outerHeight();
   var ctt = $('#contact').offset().top - $('#nav').outerHeight();

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= svc) {
        $('.scroll').removeClass('selected')  
        $('a[href="#services"]').addClass('selected');  
    }    

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ctt) {
       $('.scroll').removeClass('selected')  
       $('a[href="#contact"]').addClass('selected');  
    }   

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/357/

Comment: ? He wants the selected nav item to be red. Thats what the OP's whole question was about. ?

Comment: At least I comment. Now that your code answers the question. I will remove my down vote.

Comment: @JordyVialoux did you see my answer was older and correct from the get go. I guess not. Lame.

Comment: Also just one more thing... is it possible to have the items select if you were to manually scroll down? And when you first visit the page for the "home" item to already be selected? Many thanks again

Comment: @JordyVialoux That's another question entirely. What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I asked for this in my initial question minus the "home" element selected on load - read "If you scroll down and see the work section you will notice the nav item is selected - I am after the same functionality." from initial question. It's fine if not - just wondering if possible :-)

Comment: @JordyVialoux Give me a minute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12977/discussion-between-jordy-vialoux-and-iambriansreed)

Comment: @undefined Close however the "selected" class needs to be applied to the li - not the anchor.

Comment: @JordyVialoux okay, use can use `parent()` method, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/359/

Comment: -1 again. The fiddle defined is broken. Click the header link and notice the incorrect coloring. Once that is working: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/5Ta8j/