# Animate window with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to create a one page website that contains multiple div's about the same size as the window.The website will have a menu that will refer to each div on the page.What I want to do is animate the window when the user clicks on one of the menu links to it's coresponding div.

http://www.nistoralexandru.comule.com/div.jpg

When a user clicks on a link I need the window to animate to that div similar to this site:

http://shahkaarshah.com/

How can I do this?

Comment: "animate the window" is not nearly descriptive enough to know what you want to do.  Please describe the EXACT animation you want to see.  There are millions of different types of animations.

Comment: GIve me a min I am linking to a image that will demonstrate what I mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advanced Jquery | Scroll Nav Selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182505/advanced-jquery-scroll-nav-selected)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ta8j/76/ this fiddle will give you an idea or if you want diagonal scroll effect then read this and try to implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you're linking to is built with Flash, replicating the animation of different page elements with javascript should'nt be to hard, but there's really no quick "one size fits all" function to do it.

Here's a quick example of how it's usually done :

Build some sort of HTML structure:

```
​<div id="site">
    <div id="main" class="page">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page5">Page 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page1" class="page"><a href="#main">Back</a></div>
    <div id="page2" class="page"><a href="#main">Back</a></div>
    <div id="page3" class="page"><a href="#main">Back</a></div>
    <div id="page4" class="page"><a href="#main">Back</a></div>
    <div id="page5" class="page"><a href="#main">Back</a></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And animate it around the viewport with a little javascript:

```
$('.page a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(href).css('top'),
        left = $(href).css('left');
    $("#site").animate({top: '-'+top, left: '-'+left}, 1000);
});
```

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3UWSM/)

Answer (score 2):

You might be meaning something like accordion?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

There are many easy-to-use accordion plugins for jquery, so they might be easier to use for complex animations than coding from scratch.

Based on your added information, maybe a grid accordion such as this?
http://css-tricks.com/examples/InfoGrid/